# Apache Camel - problems parsing response from http endpoint

Tags: apache-camel

I have a route triggered by http request (POST, servlet endpoint) transforming the data using velocity to a SOAP webservice request and then posting it to the WebService using http. I'm then trying to parse the response from that, but I get binary data in the response. SOAPUI displays the correct data though.

Ideas?

```
from("servlet:///cancelCode?servletName=CamelServlet")
.to("velocity:classpath:cancelCode.vm")
.setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant("POST"))
.to(inteleOrderServiceEndpoint)
```

Response in console:

```
2012-09-19 13:22:11 DEBUG [header:] << "HTTP/1.1 200 OK[\r][\n]"
2012-09-19 13:22:11 DEBUG [header:] << "HTTP/1.1 200 OK[\r][\n]"
2012-09-19 13:22:11 DEBUG [header:] << "Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8[\r][\n]"
2012-09-19 13:22:11 DEBUG [header:] << "Content-Encoding: gzip[\r][\n]"
2012-09-19 13:22:11 DEBUG [header:] << "Transfer-Encoding: chunked[\r][\n]"
2012-09-19 13:22:11 DEBUG [header:] << "Server: Jetty(6.1.x)[\r][\n]"
2012-09-19 13:22:11 DEBUG [header:] << "[\r][\n]"
2012-09-19 13:22:11 DEBUG [content:] << "1"
2012-09-19 13:22:11 DEBUG [content:] << "0"
2012-09-19 13:22:11 DEBUG [content:] << "0"
2012-09-19 13:22:11 DEBUG [content:] << "[\r]"
2012-09-19 13:22:11 DEBUG [content:] << "[\n]"
2012-09-19 13:22:11 DEBUG [content:] << "[0x1f][0x8b][0x8][0x0][0x0][0x0][0x0][0x0][0x0][0x0][0x8d][0x92]]j[0xc3]0[0x10][0x84][0xdf]{[\n]"
2012-09-19 13:22:11 DEBUG [content:] << "[0xe3][0x3]hq[0xff]k\A[0xeb][0x98][0xb6][0x10][0xf2][0x90][0x1b][0xa8][0xf2][0xd2][0x14]$[0xad][0xd1][0xca][0xa1][0xb9]}[0xe5]Dn[0xed]bJ[0xde][0xa4][0x99][0xf9][0x16][0xcd][0xa2][0x8a]Iu[0xe8][0xf6]e[0xe3][0xf6]h[0xa8][0xc3][0xec][0xcb][0x1a][0xc7]e[0x92][0x1f][0xf3]][0x8]][0x9][0xc0]z[0x87]V[0xb1][0x88][0xee]`[0x9][0xf2][0x1f]0[0x1c][0x0][0x13][0x7]y"[0xb5]r?[0x14][0xb6]Z8[0xc][0x9a][0xac][0x8]h[0xd0][0x91][0x17][0x8e] &4[0x1a]M-z[0xe4][0x8e][0x1c][0xe3][0x84]-[0xce][0x86]9[0xa8][0xd0]s./[0xb2],[0xab][0xc6][0x1a][0xaf][0xa8][0xe2]X[0x98][0x8b][0xcf][0xd4][0x1e][0x8e][0xca] [0xc6][0x1][0xe5]iH[0x1d][0x87]l[0xd3][0xb][0xb6]Da[0x8c],[0xa6]z3[0xf5]S[0xa4](u[0xcf][0x81],[0xfa][0xb7][0x95]|[0xa1][0x83]jU[0x5][0xf5][0x5][0x8a][0xd1]*[0xb3][0xe9][0xed];zY\^][0xdf][0xdc][0xde][0xdd]?$tf.[0xc1][0xc7][0xde][0xb2]~[0xda][0xd4][0xcd]z[0xdd][0xac]F[0xec]$O:[0xc0]%[0x16][0xdc][0xf9]"*[0x98][0xaf][0xef][0xf7]>~[0x15][0xf9][\r][0xd4][0xe9][0x80][0xdd]=[0x2][0x0][0x0]"
2012-09-19 13:22:11 DEBUG [content:] << "[\r]"
2012-09-19 13:22:11 DEBUG [content:] << "[\n]"
2012-09-19 13:22:11 DEBUG [content:] << "0"
2012-09-19 13:22:11 DEBUG [content:] << "[\r]"
2012-09-19 13:22:11 DEBUG [content:] << "[\n]"
2012-09-19 13:22:11 DEBUG [content:] << "[\r]"
2012-09-19 13:22:11 DEBUG [content:] << "[\n]"
2012-09-19 13:22:11 DEBUG [header:] << "[\r][\n]"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The content is gzip encoded (eg compressed) and hence why its show as binary data.

You can uncompress this to parse the data as plain readable text. Or when you call the remote http server, you can tell the http server that you do *not* support gzip, which the remote server ought to honor and send back plain text data.

Comment: hmm suspected that, trying unmarshal().gzip()